# Adding an icon in a pdf file in JAVA

Tags: java, pdf

How can i add an letterhead icon in a pdf file?
it only print a value from the textfiled.

```
    try{
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("Payment.pdf"));
    document.open();
    document.add(new Paragraph("Payment Information", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER,18, Font.BOLD)));
    document.add(new Paragraph(" "));
    document.add(new Paragraph("Customer ID:  "+value1));
    document.add(new Paragraph("Name:  "+value2));
    document.add(new Paragraph("Date Applied:  "+value3));
    document.add(new Paragraph("Months:  "+value4));
    document.add(new Paragraph("Amount:  "+value5));
    document.add(new Paragraph("Interest:  "+value6));
    document.add(new Paragraph("Monthly Payment:  "+value7));
    document.add(new Paragraph("Total:  "+value8));
    document.close();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Saved");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, e);
    }
```

Comment: You've got classes in your code called `Document` and `PdfWriter` etc which seem to be creating the PDF file. Are these your classes, or do they come from a third-party library? If it's a library, which library are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You cadd an image or icon to pdf using `document.add(image)`. The following link will give you an example:

[Itext Add / Insert Image Into PDF](http://www.javatips.net/blog/2011/12/itext-add-insert-image-into-pdf)

The above example is using IText API.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add letter then make class extending PdfPageEventHelper of itext 
and you can add image in method predefined with name onStartPage and if you want to add end of page then you can use onEndPage